# MySQL 5.7 query only working in terminal, not in program. It fill a sorting counter

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Following query gives often an error, but works perfect in a terminal:

```
SET @counter=0;UPDATE item SET sequence=(@counter:=@counter+1) WHERE page=1 AND menu_card_id=1 ORDER BY position,id
```

What can be the cause?

Comment: what error does it give?  you say "often", does it work sometimes (not in a terminal)?

Comment: most libraries won't do multiple statements in a single request unless you tell them its ok, to limit the harm sql injection attacks can do.  how you tell them depends what mysql client library you are using

Answer (score 0):

Send you 2 queries in your app? then it is possible that the app use different connections and the var is undefined.

mofify your queries to one query like this:

```
UPDATE item i
JOIN ( SELECT  @counter:=0 ) AS init
 SET i.sequence=(@counter:=@counter+1) 
WHERE i.page=1 
AND i.menu_card_id=1 
ORDER BY i.position,i.id;
```

so the uservar @counter will be set in the same query

**sample with other table**

```
mysql> select * FROM InputTable;
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------+
| id | filenumber | my_uuid | input_street | city |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------+
|  1 |         33 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL |
|  2 |        222 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL |
|  3 |         22 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE InputTable i
    -> join (select @xx:=0) as init
    -> SET i.filenumber = (@xx := @xx+1)
    -> where i.filenumber < 199
    -> ORDER BY i.filenumber DESC;
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 2

mysql> select * FROM InputTable;
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------+
| id | filenumber | my_uuid | input_street | city |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------+
|  1 |          2 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL |
|  2 |        222 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL |
|  3 |          1 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it's a nice idea but a new error appears: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

Comment: yes, you can only do order by in the single table update syntax, not with joins

Comment: @Bart Mensfort - i have change (correct) my answer and also add a sample includes **order by**. Can you pls check these

Comment: @BerndBuffen really, you can't do that in 5.7.  https://dbfiddle.uk/-I2P0zLL  (vs 8 where you can: https://dbfiddle.uk/PgT2hdGU )